# Create calendar overlay using visual studio list instance

Tags: list, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-calendar, visual-studio-2013

I have created calendar list using visual studio 2013 with two views in List Instance. Now i want to create some calendar overlays using same views i have created in list instance.

Please help me to create calendar overlay using visual studio list instance.

I can achieve through SharePoint UI but i need solution to achieve the same using VS list instance.

Comment: it is not possible

Comment: it is possible using SharePoint UI So there must be any way to achieve this.

Comment: yes, you can do it with UI but cant do it with Instance

Answer (score 2):

What does OP mean by instance? List definition in XML? In that case maybe not, but there is code for that which I have successfully used many a time. Just stick that in an event receiver and you're good to go:

```
public static void AddCalendarOverlay(SPList targetList, string viewName, SPList overlayList, string overlayListView, string overlayName, string overlayDescription, CalendarOverlayColor color, bool alwaysShow, bool clearExisting)
{
    bool sharePoint = overlayList != null;

    SPView overlayView = overlayList.DefaultView;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(overlayListView))
    {
        if (overlayList.Views[overlayListView] != null)
        {
            overlayView = overlayList.Views[overlayListView];
        }
    }

    string linkUrl = overlayView.ServerRelativeUrl;

    SPView targetView = targetList.DefaultView;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
    {
        if (targetList.Views[viewName] != null)
        {
            targetView = targetList.Views[viewName];
        }
    }

    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
    XmlElement aggregationElement = null;
    int count = 0;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(targetView.CalendarSettings) || clearExisting)
    {
        xml.AppendChild(xml.CreateElement("AggregationCalendars"));
        aggregationElement = xml.CreateElement("AggregationCalendar");
        xml.DocumentElement.AppendChild(aggregationElement);
    }
    else
    {
        xml.LoadXml(targetView.CalendarSettings);
        XmlNodeList calendars = xml.SelectNodes("/AggregationCalendars/AggregationCalendar");
        if (calendars != null)
            count = calendars.Count;
        aggregationElement = xml.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("/AggregationCalendars/AggregationCalendar[@CalendarUrl='{0}']", linkUrl)) as XmlElement;
        if (aggregationElement == null)
        {
            if (count >= 10)
                throw new SPException(string.Format("10 calendar ovarlays already exist for the calendar {0}.", targetList.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl));
            aggregationElement = xml.CreateElement("AggregationCalendar");
            xml.DocumentElement.AppendChild(aggregationElement);
        }
    }
    if (!aggregationElement.HasAttribute("Id"))
        aggregationElement.SetAttribute("Id", Guid.NewGuid().ToString("B", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

    aggregationElement.SetAttribute("Type", sharePoint ? "SharePoint" : "Exchange");
    aggregationElement.SetAttribute("Name", !string.IsNullOrEmpty(overlayName) ? overlayName : (overlayList == null ? "" : overlayList.Title));
    aggregationElement.SetAttribute("Description", !string.IsNullOrEmpty(overlayDescription) ? overlayDescription : (overlayList == null ? "" : overlayList.Description));
    aggregationElement.SetAttribute("Color", ((int)color).ToString());
    aggregationElement.SetAttribute("AlwaysShow", alwaysShow.ToString());
    aggregationElement.SetAttribute("CalendarUrl", linkUrl);

    XmlElement settingsElement = aggregationElement.SelectSingleNode("./Settings") as XmlElement;
    if (settingsElement == null)
    {
        settingsElement = xml.CreateElement("Settings");
        aggregationElement.AppendChild(settingsElement);
    }
    if (sharePoint)
    {
        settingsElement.SetAttribute("WebUrl", overlayList.ParentWeb.Site.MakeFullUrl(overlayList.ParentWebUrl));
        settingsElement.SetAttribute("ListId", overlayList.ID.ToString("B", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        settingsElement.SetAttribute("ViewId", overlayView.ID.ToString("B", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        settingsElement.SetAttribute("ListFormUrl", overlayList.Forms[PAGETYPE.PAGE_DISPLAYFORM].ServerRelativeUrl);
    }

    targetView.CalendarSettings = xml.OuterXml;
    targetView.Update();
}
```

Most of the code is self-explanatory, but if you need any clarification I will be happy to help.

Comment: Thanks for reply & your efforts but i had completed it long time back....:)

Comment: Still, some users might find it useful :)

Comment: Yes you are right.. that's why i appreciated your effort by up-vote the answer. as i know we can do it by this way well. Thanks Again Man..:)